# S3 presigned URL NGINX reverse proxy error - SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: amazon-s3, nginx-reverse-proxy, pre-signed-url

I want to display pdfs from S3 in the browser by using [pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Instead of using the S3 URL, I reverse proxy it with NGINX to look like this:

```
URL www.my-site-url.com/public/s3-presinged-url-bucket-part-with-sign-info
```

My NGINX block definition:

```
location /public {
    proxy_pass https://XXXX.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

But S3 throws the error:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

How do I reverse proxy it correctly?

Comment: I ran into the same issue using MinIO. It seems like S3 signature version 4 takes into account _all_ the request headers when generating the presigned URLs. In my case, my reverse proxy was overwriting the host header to match the MinIO server, instead of keeping the original hostname (the one that I want to use to access S3 from the browser). Loosely related to the original question but here are MinIO docs on [how to reverse proxy with NGINX](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/integrations/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio.html).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation when proxying to presigned S3 urls. Everything worked on development machines, but failed in production because CloudFront added additional headers which changed the signature. In my case because I already had valid presigned URLs provided headers were unmolested, I added `proxy_pass_request_headers off;` to make the proxy request roughly equivalent to a direct GET request.